# Kafka consumer has no memeberAssignment and unable to consume messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I have a nestjs app that is meant to create a consumer instance, where i listen to events, and i also want to provide the consumer instance to a health-check service making sure that the consumer is healthy, without making additional connections.

I have a class to extend serverKafka

```
export class ExtendedClientKafka extends ServerKafka implements CustomTransportStrategy {
  constructor(options: KafkaOptions['options']) {
    super(options);
  }

  get publicConsumer() {
    return this.consumer;
  }

  async connect() {
    // this.consumer.subscribe({ topic: process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC });

    await this.listen(() => {
      console.log('Kafka consumer connected');
    });
  }
}
```

and it is used in kafkaService to connect

```
@Injectable()
export class KafkaService implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private client: ExtendedClientKafka;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(KafkaService.name);

  async onModuleInit() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'localhost') {
      try {
        this.client = new ExtendedClientKafka({
          client: {
            brokers: [process.env.KAFKA_BROKER],
          },
          consumer: {
            groupId: process.env.KAFKA_GROUP_ID,
            retry: { retries: 3 },
          },
        });
        await this.client.connect();
        this.logger.log('Connected to Kafka');
      } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(`Failed to connect to Kafka:, ${(error as Error).message}`);
        throw new Error('Failed to establish connection to Kafka. Please check your configuration and network.');
      }
    }
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.disconnect();
  }

  getClient(): ExtendedClientKafka {
    return this.client;
  }

  async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.client) {
      await this.client.close();
    }
  }
}
```

My kafkaservice is then used in all modules where i want the connection to kafka. My issue is that in a controller i want to use nestjs eventpattern decorator to listen for events like this

```
@Controller()
export class ConsumerController {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ConsumerController.name);
  constructor(
    private readonly kafkaService: KafkaService,
    private readonly consumerService: ConsumerService) {}

  @EventPattern(process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC)
  async handleScheduledJobs(message: Buffer) {
    this.logger.log("Received message from Kafka", message.toString(), message);
    // await this.consumerService.elaborateMessage(message);
  }
}
```

but after starting my app i join the consumer group but get no memberAssignment and unable to log any messages written to that topic. Here is a log of my consumer joining:

```
LOG [ServerKafka] INFO [ConsumerGroup] Consumer has joined the group {"timestamp":"2023-10-30T13:09:26.718Z","logger":"kafkajs","groupId":"device-parameters-manager-server","memberId":"nestjs-consumer-server-05a610ed-ea78-40fe-b2ce-0eae0d36d8bf","leaderId":"nestjs-consumer-server-05a610ed-ea78-40fe-b2ce-0eae0d36d8bf","isLeader":true,"memberAssignment":{},"groupProtocol":"RoundRobinAssigner","duration":70}
```

If use app.connectMicroservices in main.ts i am able to join and process messages but unable to share the consumer instance in my health-check service. the health-check service will require me to make a different connection each time.

Comment: By default, Kafka consumer groups read from the end of the topic and wait for new events. So, do you have any producers running? Or did you expect it to read existing data? Otherwise, for a simple connection healthcheck, you don't really need to consume/process data.